# Is "cut and come again" understood outside Australia?

Tags: phrases, australian-english

Although I haven't read the Australian children's book "The Magic Pudding", I'm familiar with the phrase "cut and come again" being used in it.

Is the phrase understood outside of Australia?

Comment: I have never heard the expression and can't even guess what it means. Could you explain it further and give a link to an example? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously it means to encourage growth in plants by pruning.

Comment: I'm Australian and not familiar with the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the phrase, '**cut-and-come-again**' is definitely used in the UK, usually to refer to types of vegetable or yummy chocolate cakes.

Here are some definitions:

1. a garden plant, especially a green vegetable or a flower, that can be repeatedly cut or harvested

> '*cut-and-come-again spinach*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

2. abundant supply, from the notion of cutting a slice, and returning at will for another

> '*It was cut, roast, and come again, for the next hour and a half.*'

Source: [Fine Dictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/Cut-and-come-again.html)

Examples of usage from the UK:

[Royal Horticultural Society: cut and come again salads](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=618)

[Nigella Lawson: recipe for chocolate fruit cake](http://www.nigella.com/recipes/view/chocolate-fruit-cake)

Comment: Ah - a word used by foodies. That explains why I haven't heard it.

Comment: Hi @chaslyfromUK yes, that would certainly explain it!

Answer (score 1):

I also know this phrase from the delightful The Magic Pudding where it is a bit of a joke because the pudding “regrows” after you cut a piece—like certain vegetables would—but also the pudding is delicious and so the characters cut a piece and then come for more. I just came across the phrase in Cranford where the first person character uses it to refer to her family liking to criticize her for a particular fault: “and in general they cut and come again.” A fine pun, I thought.

Comment: Is Cranford outside Australia? If so, where?

Comment: @Mitch Possibly it's the [British TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranford_(TV_series))? (But yes, clarification would be welcome from Anne.)

Comment: Cranford is the novel by Elizabeth Gaskell written in the 1850’s (and I wouldn’t be surprised if the BBC has done a version). Cranford is a small town in England.

Comment: @AnneSandbach Can you edit your answer to add that information? Easier to see all the info in the answer than having to scan the comments for it.

Comment: Isn't the OP in the question already referring to The Magic Pudding? Not sure I follow this answer. Welcome to the ELU community, Anne!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are at. I have never heard that phrase used by a person from the United States or Canada, and I live in the Northern United States. I have heard it used on Brit-box. I actually looked it up, because I heard it used on Agatha Raisin (I love that show), and I figured it was something British, but I guess it's Australian?

I would have to say that it didn't make it to the Americas, but it did, however, make it to western Europe.